# Centering an <hr> tag

Tags: html, centering

I'm having some trouble with my `hr` tag in HTML, as it isn't automatically centering as I expect it to. This is what my current code looks like:

```
<div id = "updatestatus" class = "statuscontainer">
    <div class = "verticalalign">Update Status</div>
</div>
<hr width = "95%">

<div id = "insertstatus" class = "statuscontainer">
    <form></form>
</div>
```

As you can see, I'm placing my `hr` tag in between two `div`s, and I believe it's supposed to automatically center, but it ends up going to the left instead. I have also tried `hr align = center` with no success either.

Edit: I just realized that when I place the entire `hr` tag within `<center></center>` it centers, but I'm still trying to figure out why it doesn't center on its own.

Comment: As shown in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/36hbk/), the `<hr>` *is* centered (I exaggerated the width there). Use your browser's inspector to see the computed style of the element (watch out for `margin`, which aligns an `<hr>`) and also what its true `align` attribute is.

Comment: HR centers fine, are you referring to Update Status?

Comment: Interesting..I'm certain that when I view my html page, HR aligns to the left instead of being centered. And I'm referring to HR unfortunately, not update status

Comment: I guess it has something to do with my CSS then. But I find that strange since I'm not floating anything to the left in any of my containers

Comment: What is your CSS like?

Answer (score 59):

Try `margin: auto;`

```
<hr style="width:100px; margin: auto;" />
```

Answer (score 5):

Simply add following css for hr tag

```
width:25%;
margin: auto;
```

Answer (score 4):

I use `!important` on my CSS

```
<hr style="width:50%; margin-left:25% !important; margin-right:25% !important;" />
```

Comment: Is important to use `!important` [only when you really need it](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/).